# I am trying to find a way to enter multiple comparison values in the where clause of a sql query by a .xlsx or .csv file

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

Suppose the following query :

```
select * 
from 
table_name a
where
a.name='@1' and
a.age=@2 and
a.org='@3';
```

Now I have .xlsx file with 3 columns of Name , Age and Organisation and 20 rows,
I need a solution where this script runs 20 times taking name age and org from rows in .xlsx file.

Comment: a) Why isn't `a.age` a number and if it is, wjhy are you putting the criteria in quotes b) why not use `... where a.name in {'Bob', 'Ted', 'Carol', 'Alice'} and a.age IN {20, 21, 25, 30} and a.org IN {'Org1','org2'}`

Answer (score 0):

Well I would go for a simple approach.

(A) Just create the query using an Excel formula and copy and paste it into a query window e.g. in D2

```
="select * from table_name a where a.name='"&A2&"' AND a.age="&B2&" AND a.org='"&C2&"'"
```

giving a result like

```
select * from table_name a where a.name='Tom' AND a.age=99 AND a.org='XYZ'
```

assuming Name, Age and Organisation are in columns A,B and C.

OR

(B) Create a table something like this and import your Excel data into it:-

CREATE TABLE Criteria(
name varchar(255),
age int,
org varchar(255),
ID in IDENTITY (1,1) not null
)

Then you can join it to your existing table and select on ID.

(actually I was thinking of SQL server import: in MySQL it may be easier to number the rows first in Excel, save them as CSV and then do the import)